# Laravel 5.5 session files don't store in storage/framework/sessions in production server

Tags: laravel, file, session, storage

I am currently maintaining a Laravel 5.5 project.

I have a copy from the production that runs on my own computer. Both of the session drivers I use are File.

Recently, I found that the production started unable to save/store any file in the `storage/framework/sessions` folder.

However, no matter how I change the permission of all the folders inside storage folder to 777, session files just don't appear in the `storage/framework/sessions` folder, while the copy that runs on my own computer just writes files as usual.

I can't figure out how the problems would be, even search every information I could find, the problem still can't be solved.

Also, I'm not sure what information that is helpful for others to inspect. The only one that might be helpful maybe the host I use of the production is Hostgator.

Comment: Could you run `storage_path()` on tinker and tell us the output?

Comment: @Mozammil I ran it on tinker and it showed the exact storage path of the production project, which is the path I mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the problem was at the .env file, the one in the production was modified by someone or occasionally to use cookie as its session driver. 
I've neglected this part, while `config/session.php` didn't have any differences between the two environments. 
After I set the session driver into file and ran `php artisan config:cache`, everything started performing correctly.